# select twitter near a specific coordinates from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, twitter

I've stored some twitter from streaming api to MongoDB. They are all in jason format and has attribute like below:

```
"geo" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : [  42.03759247,  -71.82113956 ] }
```

I'm just wondering what is the correct query to select tweet near a specific coordinates. I did it like this:

```
db.tweets.find( { coordinates : { $near : [151.1955562233925,-33.87107475181752]  , $maxDistance : 1000} } )
```

but it didn't work. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/mongodb-geospatial-queries/), you must first create a geo-spatial index to be able to query geographically:

> Now, inorder to query by geo co-ordinates, we need to create an index
>   over the “loc” field of our dealership documents.

```
db.dealerships.ensureIndex({loc:"2d"})
```

So try something like this:

```
db.tweets.ensureIndex({"coordinates":"2d"})
```

You might also need to change the structure of your "geo" property to match the following (I'm not sure about this part):

```
"geo" : { "type" : "Point", "coordinates" : { "lon":42.03759247,  "lat":-71.82113956 } }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
db.tweets.ensureIndex({"coordinates.coordinates":"2d"})
```

Query:

```
db.tweets.find({"coordinates.coordinates": {$near:[-1,-53]}}).limit(2)
```